# Triple integral between two spheres

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate
$$
\iiint_{E}(2.1 z) d V
$$
where $E$ is bounded between two spheres:
$$
x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=8.5^{2} \text { and } x^{2}+y^{2}+(z-8.5)^{2}=8.5^{2} .
$$
[Region between two spheres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qC30.png)

I am supposed to convert the integral to spherical coordinate $(\rho, \phi, \theta)$ where $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle and $\theta$ is the polar angle. I don't know how to determine the boundaries of the three variables. Please help me.

Here is my attempt

We have
$\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

The region is in the upper half of the first sphere so
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 8.5^2 \implies z = \sqrt{8.5^2 - \rho^2} \quad (1)$$

For the second sphere, it is in the lower half so I took the minus sign instead
$$x^2 + y^2 + (z-8.5)^2 = 8.5^2 \implies z = -\sqrt{8.5^2 - \rho^2} + 8.5 \quad (2)
$$

From (1) and (2), I found the intersection $\displaystyle z = 4.25, \rho = \frac{17\sqrt3}{4}$

Therefore the integral is
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{17\sqrt3}{4}}\int_{-\sqrt{8.5^2 - \rho^2} + 8.5}^{\sqrt{8.5^2 - \rho^2}} (2.1z\rho) dzd\rho d\phi$$

Comment: Please make an attempt and share. Even before finding the boundary, you need to write the equations of spheres in spherical coordinates, correct? What do you get for the second sphere? Also the least you can do is to equate $x^2 + y^2$ from both equations to find $z$ and then $r$ at intersection. That would lead you to bounds of integral. Once you show your working, we can help further.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve it by letting the boundary of z $(\sqrt{8.5^2-\rho^2}, \sqrt{ 8.5^2 - \rho^2} + 8.5)$. The integral becomes like this: $$ \iint_A  \left[\int _{\sqrt{8.5^2-\rho^2}}^{\sqrt{8.5^2 - \rho^2} + 8.5} 2.1z dz\right] dA, \quad A = \{(\rho, \phi):0\leqslant\rho\leqslant\frac{17\sqrt3}{4}, \quad 0 \leqslant\phi\leqslant2\pi\} $$

Comment: Good, I will check. You should edit the question to add your effort rather than posting in comments. You seems to be using cylindrical coordinates. I thought you wanted to solve using spherical coordinates?

Comment: Your bounds for $z$ is not correct.

Comment: You are right. I switched to cylindrical coordinates because I found it easier to solve for this problem. I have corrected my z bounds after considering either to use the equations for the lower half or the upper half of the spheres. Could you check it again?

Comment: +1 for updating the question with your effort. Your revised working is correct. Please see my answer for spherical coordinates. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working is correct for cylindrical coordinates. If you were to do it in spherical coordinates,

$x = \rho \cos\phi \sin \theta, y = \rho \sin\phi \sin\theta, z = \rho \cos\theta$

$x^2 + y^2 + (z-8.5)^2 = 8.5^2 \implies x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 17 z$

So $ \ \rho = 17 \cos\theta, 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

The sphere centered at the origin is $\rho = \dfrac{17}{2}$

At intersection of both sphere, $\rho = 17 \cos\theta = \dfrac{17}{2} \implies \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$

Now if we integrate wrt $\rho$ first and then $\theta$, we need to split it into two integrals. For $0 \leq \theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{3}$, $\rho$ is bound above by the sphere centered at the origin whereas for $\dfrac{\pi}{3} \leq \theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $\rho$ is bound above by the sphere $\rho = 17 \cos\theta$.

But if we integrate wrt $\theta$ first, we can set it up in one integral.

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{17/2} \int_0^{\arccos(\rho/17)}  1.05 \rho^3 \sin (2\theta) \ d\theta \ d\rho \ d\phi$